# onmouseover Not working with items that have a z-index higher than one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble making a website using javascript. What I want to do is have a timeline of sorts which when each node is passed over by the mouse, the information on either side is updated. However, I am unable to get on mouseover to work with the nodes. I believe this is happening because they are over the base line, with each of them having a z-index of 2. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            baseLine =  new Image()
            dash =      new Image()
            baby =      new Image()
            brokenleg = new Image()
            compsci =   new Image()
            grad =      new Image()
            inhaler =   new Image()
            orioles =   new Image()
            python =    new Image()
            qohs =      new Image()
            bus =       new Image()

            baseLine.src="LineBase.png"
            dash.src="images/dash.png"
            baby.src="images/baby.png"
            brokenleg.src="images/brokenleg.png"
            compsci.src="images/compsci.png"
            grad.src="images/grad.png"
            inhaler.src="images/inhaler.png"
            orioles.src="images/orioles.png"
            python.src="images/python.png"
            qohs.src="images/qohs.png"
            bus.src="images/bus.png"
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mouseOver()
            {
                alert(1); //testing purposes
            }   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="picture-container">
                <img id="tagImage" src="images/baby.png" name="tag" onmouseover="alert(1)"/> // this works
            </div>

            <div id="time-line">
                <img id="base" src="images/LineBase.png" />

                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" onmouseover="alert(1)"/> // but this doesn't
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
                <img class="dash" src="images/dash.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="story-box">
                <h1 id="hey">hey</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please recreate the issue with http://jsfiddle.net and using the actual urls for the images so that they are visible.

Comment: @tw http://jsfiddle.net/Habel/wfBX9/ Commented in is what I think is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Habel/wfBX9/) seems to work fine, however in Chrome and IE `#base` overlaps the second `.dash`. The reason it's not working is because, whilst you have set `z-index:2` for `.dash` you have not set a `position` of `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. Without one of these positioning properties the `z-index` will not work, and so `.dash` stays behind `#base`.

```
.dash {
    z-index:2;
    float: left;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/wfBX9/9/